# aggregate in R does not return an actual data show on the console

Tags: r, aggregate

I am trying to create an aggregate table with mean and count from the following data

```
> sample_data
   sample percent
1       A       5
2       A       2
3       A       3
4       B       7
5       B       7
6       C       4
7       C       3
8       C       2
9       C       3
10      D       5
```

I use this function

```
aggregate_sample =aggregate(sample_data[,2], list(sample_data$sample), FUN=function(x) c(mn=mean(x),ln=length(x)))
```

And from console output, I did get what I want:

```
> aggregate_sample
  Group.1     x.mn     x.ln
1       A 3.333333 3.000000
2       B 7.000000 2.000000
3       C 3.000000 4.000000
4       D 5.000000 1.000000
```

However, when I click on the Data for aggregate_sample, I only get this

```
  Group.1     x
1       A 3.333333
2       B 7.000000
3       C 3.000000
4       D 5.000000
```

Can anyone help me on how to get the right table results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the column 'x' is a `matrix` with 2 columns as we used `c(mn=mean(x),ln=length(x)` in the `FUN`.  We can change it to a regular data.frame with

```
aggregate_sample1 <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate_sample)
```

---

For these operations, another way is `dplyr`, where this can be done in a straightforward way

```
library(dplyr)
sample_data %>% 
     group_by(sample) %>%
     summarise(mn = mean(percent), ln = n())
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sample_data)[, .(mn = mean(percent), ln = .N), by = sample]
```

Comment: wow thanks a bunch, for the future is there anyway to do this instead of using do.call?

Comment: @NormanKuo I would use either `dplyr` or `data.table` instead of `aggregate` as 1) aggregate is slow, 2) with `NA` elements, have to readjust other parameters,  3), outcome is not always the expected as you have experienced

Comment: Thank you very much